# Signal-R WebSocketException (Could not resolve host)

Tags: android, xamarin, dns, signalr, signalr-hub

I've implemented signalr connection for a chat purpose inside my xamarin project.
When I test from emulator or physical devices I have no issues but monitoring app center analytics I see many issues on android devices.
I think is not such a systematic issue but occasional/randomically because not every users report chat issues.
Anyway this is a raw issue:

```
{
  "length": 0,
  "offset": 0,
  "id": "05b43266-be47-408d-9531-620c297cd647",
  "exception": {
    "type": "System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException",
    "message": "Unable to connect to the remote server",
    "stackTrace": "  at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsyncCore (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocketOptions options) [0x00391] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000d1] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.DefaultWebSocketFactory (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.WebSocketConnectionContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x003f4] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.Internal.WebSocketsTransport.StartAsync (System.Uri url, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00123] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartTransport (System.Uri connectUrl, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.HttpTransportType transportType, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c5] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.SelectAndStartTransport (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00103] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsyncCore (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00139] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnection.StartAsync (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.TransferFormat transferFormat, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00092] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0011e] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionFactory.ConnectAsync (System.Net.EndPoint endPoint, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001d3] in <29776854af8e4d91b04ad040fb694276>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncCore (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000b3] in <b03537a6aa1649e39b2dfc824bae0d16>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsyncInner (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x001b6] in <b03537a6aa1649e39b2dfc824bae0d16>:0 \n  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.HubConnection.StartAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00092] in <b03537a6aa1649e39b2dfc824bae0d16>:0 \n  at MyPad.App.InitHubConnection () [0x000f2] in <6226c75697b04654886ef8ba42c50775>:0 ",
    "innerExceptions": [
      {
        "type": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
        "message": "Could not resolve host 'mypadapi.azurewebsites.net'",
        "stackTrace": "  at System.Net.Dns.Error_11001 (System.String hostName) [0x00015] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String hostName) [0x00021] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00052] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (System.String hostNameOrAddress) [0x00056] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke(object,intptr)\n  at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) <Module>.end_invoke_IPAddress[]__this___IAsyncResult(System.IAsyncResult)\n  at System.Net.Dns.EndGetHostAddresses (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00019] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <02432465956f42cebcacad2804482ab1>:0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n\n  at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectSocketAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0007e] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 \n  at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsyncCore (System.Uri uri, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocketOptions options) [0x000d7] in <3a601a1b3c5047a7ab4dafecfdb16515>:0 ",
        "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin"
      }
    ],
    "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin"
  },
  "properties": {
    "idUser": "9594"
  },
  "appId": "9fdb000f-278c-4f5b-9256-507e05d0ce0c",
  "installId": "9dcf8dca-a6fe-4480-85ab-4649dd9dec16",
  "isTestMessage": false,
  "timestamp": "2023-08-27T07:40:24.621Z",
  "sid": "76fbde8b-0b52-4339-97d7-8a2d590321be",
  "device": {
    "sdkName": "appcenter.android",
    "sdkVersion": "4.3.1",
    "wrapperSdkVersion": "4.4.0",
    "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin",
    "model": "SM-S908B",
    "oemName": "samsung",
    "osName": "Android",
    "osVersion": "13",
    "osBuild": "TP1A.220624.014",
    "osApiLevel": 33,
    "locale": "it_IT",
    "timeZoneOffset": 120,
    "screenSize": "720x1404",
    "appVersion": "2.2",
    "carrierName": "vodafone IT",
    "carrierCountry": "it",
    "appBuild": "72",
    "appNamespace": "com.***.***",
    "wrapperRuntimeVersion": "13.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Anyway is important to say the signalr connection works during my tests and for ios devices always, so I think the implementation is correct, but if you desire more info about implementation i can give you.

I'm connecting to the host using DNS.
Seems to be a dns resolving issue, but i tested on android emulator and not have this issue.
Thank you!

I make some research and I just check maybe is a dns problem but im not totally sure and I not have public static ip so is not possible to try this solution.

Comment: What is your question?  This appears to be a DNS issue.  There's not a lot you can do about that.

Comment: How is possible in Ios everything works? And if exists a easy workaround for this issue. These are my question.